# Adding patch to pig

Tags: patch, apache-pig

I'd like to add this [patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2417) to my version of Pig. How do I do that?

Comment: See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/HowToContribute#HowToContribute-Applyingapatch